# Inline Editing Problem in Checkbox

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I am facing problem in InlineEditSupport for checkbox. i have create list of record for custom object. i am trying to edit single record which belong to list. it's working for input field or Picklist but when i try to edit checkbox field not work.

## Visualforce

```
<apex:repeat value="{!VersionList}" var="VObj">
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Version Edit">            
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel >Version</apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:outputField value="{!VObj.Version__c}">
        <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick" changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
    </apex:outputField>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel >Date</apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:outputField value="{!VObj.Date__c}">
        <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick" changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
</apex:outputField>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel >Author</apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:outputField value="{!VObj.Author__c}">
        <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick" changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
    </apex:outputField>
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
<apex:outputLabel >Is API Visible</apex:outputLabel>
        <apex:outputField value="{!VObj.Is_API_Visible__c}">
            <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick" changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
        </apex:outputField>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>            
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel >Is DB Visible</apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:outputField value="{!VObj.Is_DB_Visible__c}">
        <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick" changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
    </apex:outputField>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>                            
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel >Is Templates Visible</apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:outputField value="{!VObj.Is_Templates_Visible__c}">
        <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick" changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
    </apex:outputField>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:pageBlockSection>            
</apex:repeat>
```

## Apex

```
public List<Primary_Version__c> VersionList {get;set;}
public Proposal__c pOne {get;set;}
public String pId {get;set;}
public ProposalDetailACE(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
       controller.addFields(new List<String>{'Expiration_Date__c','Opportunity_Name__r.Name','Created1_By__c','Customer_Name__c','Date__c'});
        pOne = (Proposal__c)controller.getRecord();
        pId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');    

        initalization();
    }
public void initalization(){
VersionList  = [SELECT Is_Templates_Visible__c,Is_API_Visible__c,Is_DB_Visible__c,Date__c,Author__c,Version__c from Primary_Version__c where Proposal__c =:pId];
}
public void updateMethod(){
  update VersionList;
}
```

Comment: Are you clicking out of the checkbox field before clicking the button to save? One of the annoying parts of inlineeditsupport. You have to leave the field for the change to be noticed, onblur iirc

Comment: Hi @Eric, Thank you for reply. yes ! we are clicking out of the checkbox field before save button. Can you share any link to achieve this solution.